# Formatar Hora num data frame em Python

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando formatar a coluna que trás as horas com os milesimos, isso é, para tirar os milesimos e visualizar hh:mm:ss apenas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que a forma mais simples é recriar todos os valores da coluna com um objeto datetime.time que copie a hora, minuto e segundos e ignore os microssegundos da coluna original.

Gosto de colocar código que outras pessoas possam executar a partir do zero, sem ter que ficar pensando em como criar um dataframe onde ele possa ser aplicado - o exemplo seria:

```
import datetime as dt, pandas as pd

z = pd.DataFrame({"hora": [dt.time(23,59,37, 159245)]})
```

no terminal do ipython::

```
In [566]: print(z)                                                                                                     
              hora
0  23:59:37.159245
```

Aí, para recriar a coluna "hora":

```
z["hora"] = z["hora"].apply(lambda t:dt.time(t.hour, t.minute, t.second))
```

E o resultado:

```
In [568]: print(z)                                                                                                     
       hora
0  23:59:37
```

O que foi feito: o método `apply` de Series e DataFrames recebe como primeiro argumento uma função que recebe a linha ou coluna (no caso de um dataframe) ou o valor da célula (no caso de uma série) e devolve um resultado. Esse resultado é usado como valor de uma nova célula. No caso, defini uma função "lambda" que recebe um valor "t", que se assume ser um `datetime.time`, e gera um outro `datetime.time`, mas usando só as informações de hora, minuto e segundos. 
A coluna "hora" no dataframe original é substituída pela nova, com o sinal de "=".

(No seu data frame do exemplo, obviamente, é só fazer o mesmo para a coluna "Hora Original")

Outro detalhe importante: esse método efetivamente muda os valores na coluna, não apenas a visualização da mesma. Se quiser manter os valores originais e mudar apenas a apresentação, a abordagem tem que ser diferente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo. Abs.

Answer (score 3):

Pressupondo que você tem a hora em `string`, você pode converter para um objeto `datetime`, fazendo:

```
from datetime import datetime
hora_string = '18:34:23.123'  # Valor da primeira linha
objeto_datetime = datetime.strptime(hora_string, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Depois para converter de volta para `string` no formato desejado (mais formatos [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime)), faça:

```
objeto_datetime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Vai resultar em:

```
'18:34:23'
```

Mais detalhes na [documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).

Comment: Boa resposta, mas no caso ele tem um dataframe do Pandas - o approach com objetos de Pandas é bem diferente do usado no Python puro - em geral, temos pelo menos que nos preocupar em usar os métodos dos próprios objetos de Pandas que permitam realizar as operações desejadas. (Nesse caso ele tem uma coluna cujos elementos já são objetos compatíveis com o `datetime.time` do Python)

Comment: Concordo 100% com você @jsbueno.

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser Posso adicionar uma sugestão?

Comment: Claro que sim, @Terry!

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser Os moderadores falaram que minha edição deveria ser uma resposta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode converter a coluna **Hora Original** para `datetime` usando a função (1)`to_datetime` e extraindo somente a **hora,minuto e segundo** com (2)`strftime`

```
df['somente Horas'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hora Original'], format= '%H:%M:%S.%f') \
                        .apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```